# Swipe right/left menu bar in html using css file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here, actually I'm not able to *insert* swipe **left/right menu bar** onto my website

Below are some code from which I've tried doing, but it's not been designed :

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">Design
```

> Please do help me to fix this issue in my coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create the quick example for you please check this.
You can solve your problem byusing css property **float:left** or **float:right**.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="sidemenu">
    <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">Design</a></li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
<style>
.container
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#CCC;
}

.sidemenu
{
  float:right;
}
</style>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/a86vd7ft/2/)

Comment: Answers should contain everything needed to solve the question in the answer itself, you can add a code snippet to show the code in your JS fiddle. (Also, please provide some explanation of what you have done and how it solves the askers problem)

Comment: Actually I'm not able to design it as swipe left or right menu bar using this code...

Comment: @AyushBharti can you show me the code or create a example into jsfiddle to understand.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you shold use just

```
float:left;
```

or

```
float:right;
```